# Manipulate state with react hooks,

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I need to change one specific value to a nested object inside my state, so I want to clone the state with the old state + the new value that needs to be changed.

My state looks like that:

```
{
    "startDate": "2020-12-04T00:00:00.000Z",
    "endDate": "2022-12-04T00:00:00.000Z",
    "yearlySummary": [
        {
            "year": "11/2020-11/2021",
            "data": {
                "actualUsage": 0,
                "actualUsagePayment": 0,
                "actualFixedFee": 57600,
                "actualTotalPayment": 57600,
                "pricePerUnit": 110.39999999999999,
                "forecastUsagePayment": 500,
                "totalUsage": 500,
                "totalPayment": 500,
                "remainingUsagePayment": 0,
                "remainingFixedFee": 0,
                "remainingTotalPayment": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "year": "11/2021-11/2022",
            "data": {
                "actualUsage": 0,
                "actualUsagePayment": 0,
                "actualFixedFee": 57600,
                "actualTotalPayment": 57600,
                "pricePerUnit": 110.39999999999999,
                "forecastUsagePayment": 300,
                "totalUsage": 300,
                "totalPayment": 300,
                "remainingUsagePayment": 0,
                "remainingFixedFee": 0,
                "remainingTotalPayment": 0
            }
        }
    ],
    "total": {
        "actualUsage": 0,
        "actualUsagePayment": 0,
        "actualFixedFee": 115200,
        "actualTotalPayment": 115200,
        "pricePerUnit": 220.79999999999998,
        "forecastUsagePayment": 800,
        "totalUsage": 800,
        "totalPayment": 800,
        "remainingUsagePayment": 0,
        "remainingFixedFee": 0,
        "remainingTotalPayment": 0
    }
}
```

I need to change 3 values of the keys from inputField with onChange function:
forecastUsagePayment,
remainingUsagePayment,
totalUsage

so my input fields look like this:

```
data.yearlySummary.map((year, index) => (
  <input
   className={classes.input}
   name="forecastUsagePayment"
   key={index}
   onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, index)}
   value={year.data.forecastUsagePayment}
  />
))
```

How the onChange function should look like?

So far all I have got is this:

```
  const handleChange = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setData((prevData) => ({
      ...prevData,
      // What should come next?
    }));
  };
```

Comment: You should get a copy of the object, change the fields, then set the state object to the copied object

Comment: I know what I should do, I just not quite sure how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty common problem in react, updating state especially when they have nested data

You could have thought a little bit and  get a solution, but I understand where u come from

your handle change function should be something like this

```js
    const handleChange = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const yearlySummaryCopy = [...data.yearlySummary];
    yearlySummaryCopy[index].data[name] = value;
    setData((prevData) => ({
      ...prevData,
      yearlySummary: yearlySummaryCopy
    }));
  };
```

here the data variable is the variable where you stored your state ....
if you are using class based components , you could say it like this.state.data

You can also check the code sandbox at https://codesandbox.io/s/great-hugle-4fuby?file=/src/App.js:1449-1730

Comment: Exactly! Thank you so much!